# Port no. For Web socket when using stormpath

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, stormpath

so I have a node. js Web application built using express.

on this app I pass custom data to the node server using socket.io and it's then supposed to pass this data to stormpath.

When I was testing this locally it worked fine but since I've launched it on Openshift the socket is no longer working.

I think I may be using the wrong port number for the socket? or else am I just doing this completely wrong?? Thank you in advance

Server=app.js..

```
server = require('http').createServer(app, function(request,response){
    console.log('Connection');
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    response.write('hello socket');
    response.end();
}); // by excluding 'var' makes the variable Global

/*io = require('socket.io')(server);*/ // by excluding 'var' makes the variable Global
io = require('socket.io')(8000);
io.configure(function(){io.set("transports", ["websocket"]);});


var index_routes = require('./routes/index');
var auth_routes = require('./routes/auth');

var strategy = new StormpathStrategy({
    expansions: 'customData'
});

server.listen(80, function(){
    console.log('listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

In the Following Code favlist is an array of custom data stored on stormpath as json object

Client=script.js...

```
 var socket = io.connect('ws://zaos-cheffernan087.rhcloud.com:8000',{
    transports: ['websocket','flashsocket','htmlfile','xhr-polling','jsonp-polling']
  });

    socket.on('message', function(data){
    console.log(data.message + ' has been set to client favourites');

    console.log('custom Data = '+ data); 

   // console.log(data.message.playlist);
    var fromStorm = data;
   // console.log(fromStorm);
    var split = new Array;
    for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++){
        split.unshift(fromStorm[j]);



    }
```

Index.js..

```
io.on('connection',function(socket){


      socket.emit('message', cd );

      /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */


      socket.on('client_data', function(data){

        nf = data;
        process.stdout.write('nf = '+ nf);

        update();


      }); 



  });

  function update(){

    req.user.getCustomData(function(err, data) {


    var oldStormpath = data.favList;
    console.log('oldStormpath = ' + oldStormpath);

    data.remove('favList');
    data.save(function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
  });

     data.favList = nf;

    data.save(function() {
      res.send('Your information has been updated!');
    });
  });


  }
```

Comment: Can you provide more information / code? It sounds like this could be a number of issues. How are you setting it up on OpenShift -- etc?

Comment: @rdegges Yeah no problem, I'll grab my code now, what do you mean setting it up on openshift?? Do you mean how am I uploading it??

Comment: @rdegges there's my code, apologies for the weird variable names, really hoping you can spot a problem because i haven't been able to use my socket for two months

Comment: Your stormpath code looks fine -- I'm not sure what else might be causing the issue other than potential deployment environment problems :x

Comment: okay thanks, I think I'm gonna try to use an ajax request instead of the web- socket